# After update UnGoogled-Chromium Web-Browser is not connecting to the internet

Tags: networking, chromium, browser

I've been using the UnGoogled-Chromium Web-Browser for two years now and never had any problems with it until yesterday, the only thing I did was an update

**Web-Browser Version:**

```
Version 95.0.4638.54 (Official Build, ungoogled-chromium) Ubuntu (64-bit)
```

**Update command:**

```
apt autoclean && apt clean && apt update --fix-missing && apt --fix-broken install && apt upgrade && apt dist-upgrade && apt autoremove
```

since then the browser doesn't want to connect to the internet anymore.
The way I see it, the browser is trying to connect via Bluetooth instead of WiFi.

**Browser launch command:**

```
chromium --proxy-server=http://127.0.0.1:8118
```

**Output:**

```
[5562:5562:0113/092248.116485:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(374)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
[5533:5587:0113/092249.595268:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(230)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking Bluetooth availability started. Please report if there is no report that this ends.
[5533:5587:0113/092249.595304:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(233)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking Bluetooth availability ended.
[5533:5587:0113/092249.595311:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(236)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking default browser status started. Please report if there is no report that this ends.
[5533:5587:0113/092249.616362:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(240)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking default browser status ended.
[5533:5553:0113/092251.736884:ERROR:ev_root_ca_metadata.cc(841)] Failed to register OID: 0
[5533:5533:0113/092312.399123:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(642)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager.GetManagedObjects: object_path= /: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
[5533:5533:0113/092314.602459:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [09:23:14.602] Bluetooth: bluetooth_adapter_bluez.cc:100 Failed to unregister pairing agent: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I found out that the browser extension **uBlock Origin** blocks any connection. As soon as I disable  **uBlock Origin**, the browser works.
I then uninstalled  **uBlock Origin 1.33.2** and installed the latest version **1.40.8**, no change, the extension blocks all connections of the web browser.
What can I do?
I need this script and add blocker, is the best one.